# Convertir de string a DateTime en VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Mi aplicación permite importar contenido de un archivo de Excel a un DataGridView, con el objetivo de luego mandar a guardar todo el contenido a una BD, una de las columnas es tipo fecha pero con el formato "MM/dd/yyyy", esa fecha antes de mandarla a la BD la introduzco en una variable de tipo `string`, lo que yo quiero es cambiar el formato a "dd/MM/yyyy" y poder enviarla a la BD con ése formato, el código que uso es el siguiente:

```
Dim fecha As String = ""
fecha = fila.Cells("F1").Value
Dim formato As String = ""
formato = Format(CDate(fecha), "dd/MM/yyyy")
agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(formato))
```

> El error me lo manda al momento de evaluar la fecha "09/13/2017"

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias respuestas sobre como convertir un `String` a `DateTime`. Son correctas, pero lo que pasa en tu situación es que tienes un problema de concepto que es muy común y que voy a intentar aclarar en la mia.

> una de las columnas es tipo fecha pero con el formato "MM/dd/yyyy"

No,no es así.Los campos de fecha,tanto en VB.Net como en las Bases de datos,**no tienen formato**. Se almacenan como un valor númerico. Por ejemplo, en SqlServer se almacena utilizando 8 bytes, 4 para la fecha (se guardan el número de dias desde el 1 de Enero de 1900) y 4 para la hora (número de ticks desde la medianoche). El formato es una representación de este dato cuando se transforma en una cadena.

Analizando tu código:

```
formato = Format(CDate(fecha), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Aquí lo que haces es convertir un `String` a `Datetime`, para volver a convertirlo en `String`

```
agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(formato))
```

y aquí,ese `String` vuelves a convertirlo a `Datetime`. Para qué tanta conversión?

Así debería ser tu código:

```
Dim fecha As String = ""
fecha = fila.Cells("F1").Value
agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", CDate(fecha))
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar `DateTime.TryParseExact` parar obtener una fecha para luego convertirla con el formato que deseas o sino tendrías que recorrer tu cadena.

```
Dim fecha As DateTime   
DateTime.TryParseExact(fila.Cells("F1").Value, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, fecha)    
agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JcJ8og)

---

**Referencia:**

- [Método DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Si el valor String de fecha es "09/13/2017" (formato `dd/MM/yyyy`), necesitas convertirlo a un valor adecuado que sería `MM/dd/yyyy`, puedes realizarlo usando [**ParseExact()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) :

```
 Dim fecha = "09/13/2017"
 Dim fechaConvertida As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha , "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

de esta forma obtendría el valor de la fecha en el formato correcto el cual  sería:

```
13/09/2017 12:00:00 a.m.
```

pero también puedes aplicar un formato si deseas el valor convertido a String, mediante el método `.ToString()`:

`fechaConvertida.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

para obtener : `13/09/2017`

---

de acuerdo a tu código se realizaría de esta forma:

```
Dim fecha As String = ""
fecha = fila.Cells("F1").Value
Dim fechaConvertida As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha , "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fechaConvertida.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Dim fecha As String = fila.Cells("F1").Value
Dim formato As Date = Format(CDate(fecha), "dd/MM/yyyy")
Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(formato))https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/170881/edit#
```

```
Dim fecha As String = fila.Cells("F1").Value
Dim formato As Date = Format(CDate(fecha), "dd/MM/yyyy")
Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(formato))

' No le pasabas un Formato de variable de Fecha...
```